# Dyadic product of two Boolean matrices

Tags: matrices, boolean-algebra, algorithmic-game-theory

I'm currently working in game theory, and have the following equilibrium $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\end{bmatrix}$.  I'd like to show the trivial equilibrium which results from this is given by the following dyadic product:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}  \otimes  \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Which I've computed to be:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 &0\\
0&1&0
\end{bmatrix}$$

For my research, it's enough to show this computation is correct for it to be a trivial equilibrium.  Is this computation correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understanding the dyadic product is given by the following:

$$\begin{matrix}
[a & b & c]
\end{matrix} \otimes \begin{matrix}
[d & e & f]\\
\end{matrix} = \begin{matrix}
ad & ae & af\\
bd & be & bf\\
cd & ce & cf
\end{matrix}$$

The computation of the given dyadic product is correct.